# How to register an interface and register methods using QtDbus?

Tags: c++, qt, dbus, qtdbus

I want to register an interface and methods on QtDbus.

In glib Dbus we have have a method g_dbus_register_interface(.. ,.. , .., ..).

Is there a way I can do the same using QtDbus?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use QDBusConnectionInterface::registerService and QDBusConnectionInterface::registerObject. Follow this manual for a complete guide: http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/Creating_Interfaces.